# How to add a font-awesome icon into @Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I have a following problem: How can I add a fa-user icon into my textbox?

I have a following code:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="row">
     <div class="container col-md-12">
          @*@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })*@
          <i class="fa fa-user col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

The "i" element is not visible on my site view in browser.
If it is imposible there is any posibility to add this icon to my site?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of what you currently have?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need to write out the HTML yourself rather than using the HTML helper.

Comment: <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              </div> try this html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is you just need to look on generated html of mvc and compare with code that have icons. Code will be the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email Address" })
</div>
```

Please mark as answer if I helped.

Comment: See below my answer, the one that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can use the Font awesome unicode codes for display.  Example (value=....):

```
 <input type=“submit” value="&#xf0f6 My blog" class=“fa fa-input”>
```

Found at https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/solved-adding-font-awesome-icons-to-an-input-button/74139/6

You can find the unicode related code at:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=solid

Should work with any similar items.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      </div>
       @Html.TextBox(Model.UserName, GetHtmlAttributes(Model, "form-control"))
    </div>
```